# Chinese mapping number routing

Tags: java, hash-map

I want to design Chinese mapping number routing. How can I improve this code in the method `mapRouting`?

I want to use reflect auto get method name by providing a value without `if` `else`, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
public class FwMappingChi {

    public static Map<String, String> mapRouting(String mapName){
        if(mapName == "ACTION") {
            return ACTION;
        }
        else if(mapName == "ENVIRONMENT") {
            return ENVIRONMENT;
        }
        else if(mapName == "RULE_TYPE") {
            return RULE_TYPE;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static final Map<String, String> ACTION = new HashMap<String, String>(){
        {
            put("0", "新增");
            put("1", "刪除");
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static final Map<String, String> ENVIRONMENT = new HashMap<String, String>(){
        {
            put("0", "正式環境");
            put("1", "長期UAT");
            put("2", "測試需求");
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static final Map<String, String> RULE_TYPE = new HashMap<String, String>(){
        {
            put("0", "系統間連接");
            put("1", "系統間連接");
            put("2", "人員維護用");
            put("3", "提供服務用");
            put("4", "User對外連接");
        }
    };
}
```

example:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> exportDatas = fwApplyListDetailMapper.getExportQuery(idsArr);
List<List<String>> pdfValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < exportDatas.size(); i++) {
    List<String> record = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> map = exportDatas.get(i);
    for (String index : headerIndex) {
        Object value = map.get(index);

        if(FwMappingChi.mapRouting(index) != null) {
            record.add(FwMappingChi.mapRouting(index).get(String.valueOf(value)));
        }

    }
    pdfValues.add(record);
    record = null;
}
```

Comment: Please provide examples of how these maps are used.

Comment: okok have update my question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Example of using reflection.

```
public static Map<String, String> mapRouting(Class<?> declaringClass, String mapName)
        throws IllegalAccessException {

    if (declaringClass == null || mapName == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Field[] declaredFields = declaringClass.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if (mapName.equals(field.getName())) {
            return (Map<String, String>) field.get(mapName);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, String> map = mapRouting(FwMappingChi.class, "ACTION");
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

I suggest you look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You could simply put your maps in a map, as the mapRouting function is nothing but a simple lookup.

Prepare somewhere

```
private static final Map<String, Map<String, String>> MASTER = new HashMap<>() {
   {
       put("ACTION", ACTION);
       put("ENVIRONMENT", ENVIRONMENT);
       put("RULE_TYPE", RULE_TYPE);
   }
};
```

And simply access that map:

```
public static Map<String, String> mapRouting(String mapName) {
    return MASTER.get(mapName);
}
```

BTW: in times of Java 10 you should really use `Map.of` instead of anonymous map subclasses.

Comment: that's good but MASTER  map always null why ?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code, using wrong scoping or whatever. To solve this, prepare a minimal example and ask over at stackoverflow.